# How can I find which commit removed a file from git?

Tags: git, version-control, grep, git-log

If I have a file under git e.g. an image png that was removed from the repository, how can I find which commit removed it?
Also I would like to search even if I am not 100% about the file name e.g. if it was `some_image.png` or `some_image_icon.png` for instance

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
git log --diff-filter=D -- *some_image_*.png
```

Or (if you know the path):

```
git log --diff-filter=D -- path/to/file/some_image_*.png
```